# Embedded Flash video: scrolling bug in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, embed, vimeo

I need to embed a Vimeo video in Flash format inside an iframe. But on scrolling down the page, the video appears to "stick" in position - only in Internet Explorer (v9, 10 and 11).

See the following web page as a demo. Resize your window to create a vertical scroll bar, then scroll down.

http://www.kieranpotts.com/staging/up/test.html

Here's a screenshot showing the sort of visual effect that occurs on scroll.

http://www.kieranpotts.com/staging/up/screenshot.png

Here's the embed code used in the page:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"
    src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/moogaloop/6.0.17/moogaloop.swf" 
    frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The URL returns an HTML document with the following contents in the body:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" 
    src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/moogaloop/6.0.17/moogaloop.swf" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Click on the iframe, and the video snaps into its correct position again. Lots of similar iframe-related issues have been reported on Stack Overflow, but I can't find this particular one.

Any takers?

We need to support Internet Explorer 9-11.

Comment: Can you post the existing code that is responsible for the embedding?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the embed code.